# Initialise Boost.MultiArray when defined inside struct?

Tags: c++, boost, data-structures, multidimensional-array

Say I have a struct like this:

```
struct someDataType
{
    boost::multi_array<int,3> data;
};
```

How do I then initialise the array? I already tried this but it doesn't seem to work:

```
someDataType container;
container.data=boost::multi_array<int,3>(boost::extents[5][5][5]);
```

The program crashes at runtime with that code; when compiled as debug, it throws an `assertion failed` from somewhere inside the Boost code.

Any help will be much appreciated :)

**EDIT:** I just realised I had written that bit of code incorrectly. I mean, I had it correct in the program, but when I copied it to SO I generalised it and made a mistake. Now fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, your declaration of someDataType only specifies how many dimensions your multi_array has, not the extents.

You have to set extents before dealing with container.data so that Boost could allocate memory for it. The easy way to do it is by using "resize":

```
  container.data.resize(boost::extents[5][5][5]);
```

You can also add a constructor to someDataType and set extents there:

```
someDataType::someDataType(): data(boost::extents[5][5][5]){}
```

As for program crash, it seems you pasted something wrong, it would fail compilation. If second "data" is omitted, snippet would compile but crash. The reason is that such assignment fails the "precondition" specified in Multi Array docs: shape of the source and the shape of the destination should be the same. However, left hand side has shape [0][0][0] while right hand side has extents [5][5][5]

Comment: _"it seems you pasted something wrong"_ Indeed I did. I noticed that 17 minutes ago and edited ;)

Comment: You did. I think I understand why it's failing now. Thanks, I'll give your answer a try and then mark it as the answer if it proves correct (which I believe it will) :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use aggregate initialization:

```
someDataType container = { boost::multi_array<int,3>(boost::extents[5][5][5]) };
```

or provide a default constructor

```
struct someDataType
{
    boost::multi_array<int,3> data;
    someDataType() : data(boost::extents[5][5][5]) {}
};

someDataType container;
```

or, to make your code work almost as written, you could use resize:

```
struct someDataType
{
    boost::multi_array<int,3> data;
};

someDataType container;
container.data.resize(boost::extents[5][5][5]);
```

Comment: `someDataType container = { boost::multi_array<int,3>(boost::extents[5][5][5]) };` What is that actually doing? And why does `container.data=boost::multi_array<int,3>(boost::extents[5][5][5]);` not work? I can't work out what the particular difference is between my code and yours that makes you believe (or that you know) will fix my problem.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try the resize method. That's the first thing you've said that makes sense to me :)

Comment: @Clonkex initialization (`someDataType container = ...`) calls the constructor, which creates the multiarray, assignment ( `container.data=...` ) calls copy assignment operator, which attempts to replace the elements of an already existing multiarray (of size 0x0x0) with the elements of the array on the right (of size 5x5x5)

Comment: Yes, Michael's answer explained that for me. They were both good answers but unfortunately for you Michael's one is more applicable to my knowledge level :)